# Bamboo stage are disabled during release from Jira

Tags: jira, bamboo

I've integrated Jira and Bamboo. And from Jira, I'm releasing the version by choosing "Build and Release" -> With build -> choosing the Plan(which list out the stages).

Problem here is I couldn't able to select the stages for the build.

Below page says that, we can choose the stage for the New build

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/running-a-bamboo-build-when-releasing-a-version-764478184.html[image]

Note: I'm using Jira v8.5.2

Can anyone please help me on the above issue

Answer (score 0):

Stages should be available for selection only if they're manual

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I can able to select the stage. My problem here is for example, I have four stage(PAT,DEV,STG,UAT) if i select the stage as STG, then first 3 stages(PAT,DEV,STG) are running. Is there any way to run only the selected stage alone ? From the Bamboo documentation, I understood that the stages will run in sequential order. But is there any way to run only the selected stage ? I'm using Bamboo v6.9.2

Comment: It's not possible to run stages independently. They're sequential as documented. If you need independent executions look at deployment projects. It allows to configure environments which can be populated with build artifacts independently https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/deployment-projects-338363438.html